# How to compile and run a program in Atom? I get this "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, atom-editor

I try to launch a simple program in Atom, but console shows me next message: "'C:\Users\name\Downloads\Lab\Test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
How to fix it?

I installed MinGW, added new Path in environment variables.
Also, I installed gpp-complier package by kriscross07, and added for C++ Complier Options this line: "-c -Wall -std=c++17" (before I tried "-std=c++11 -Wall" how it was said in my course manual, but I couldn't launch the console, I got an error "no a such file or directory).

Any thoughts can be helpful, thank you!
Microsoft 11.

Comment: Is there a `C:\Users\name\Downloads\Lab\Test.exe`?

Comment: Console asks \Test, file is Test.cpp, the way is correct

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have Atom as default application for the `.cpp` extension, then you can just launch the default application on that file by running:

```
START C:\Users\name\Downloads\Lab\Test.cpp
```

Make sure to include the full path including the `.cpp` extenstion.